# How to make an inner join , Left join , right join between 2 table using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

**How to write a JPA query that make a join between 2 entities**

```
EntityA

@Id

long id

String field1 String field2

EntityB

@Id

String field1

@Id

String field2
```

How can I write a join like This in JPQL

```
select * from entityA,entityB where entityB.field1 = entityA.field1
and entityB.field2 = entityA.field2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could change your code to include reference to EntityB in EntityA you can use this:

```
CriteriaQuery<EntityA> cq = cb.createQuery(EntityA.class);
Root<EntityA> root = cq.from(EntityA.class);
Join<EntityA, EntityB> join = root.join(EntityA_.entityBs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join:

```
select * from entityA inner join entityB on entityA.field1 = entityB.field2
```

Left outer join:

```
select * from entityA left outer join entityB on entityA.field1 = entityB.field2
```

Change entities and use left join again instead of right join:

```
select * from entityB left outer join entityA on entityA.field1 = entityB.field2
```

Useful posts: http://chrisiecorner.blogspot.com/2012/12/jpa-and-outer-joins.html, [RIGHT JOIN in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210269/right-join-in-jpql)

So better way is criterion query, see: [Querying Relationships Using Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html)