# JPQL Right Join

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql, right-join

After search I came to know that there is no Right Join in JPQL. I saw there is another way to achieve it using JPA bidirectional (not right join but using pojo object ) but one thing I noticed in console that it make many calls to database for eg see below table.

```
       Flat Table                   UserToFlat                    User
| Flat_ID  |  Flat No  |      | ID   |  Flat_ID | User_ID |    | User_ID | Name |
|  1       |    101    |      | 1    |    1     |  1      |    |   1     | XYZ  |  
|  2       |    102    |      | 2    |    2     |  2      |    |   2     | PQR  |
|  3       |    103    |      | 3    |    3     |  3      |    |   3     | ABC  |
|  4       |    104    |
```

I want all rows from flat table and only matching rows from User table

```
// below query do not work as flat is having primary key and usertoflat having foreign key
select f, u from FlatEntity f left join f.userToFlatEntity uf join uf.user u;

// now if I try right join then jpql throws exception
select f from UserToFlatEntity uf right join uf.flatEntity f;
```

Now if I use jpql birectional and fetch using object for eg

```
// suppose I have FlatEntity Object 
flatEntity.getUserToFlatEntity();
```

above code will hits database for every flat no with where condition flat_ID = ?     (4 times in this case ) and I think this not good performance wise.

So is there any way I can JPQL achieve right join with out effecting performance.

Entity Configuration

```
public class FlatEntity {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "flatEntity")
    private UserToFlatEntity userToFlatEntity;

   // getter setter
}

public class UserToFlatEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "flatId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private FlatEntity flatEntity;
}

public class UserEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userEntity")
    private Set<UserToFlatEntity> userToFlatEntitySet;
}

Exception
 Path expected for join!
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:369)
```

Comment: There is right join in JPQL.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Can you please give me some example because I am getting error. I am posting my mapping configuration.

Comment: I don't see any `from` clauses in your queries. I suggest you go through some Hibernate/JPA tutorials first.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic it was my typing error not having from clause

Comment: Ok, could you then please post the errors you get with right join?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic JPQL query `select f from UserToFlatEntity uf right join uf.flatEntity ` error I am getting `No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'f' {originalText=f}`

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I was f alias to flatEntity in query and because of that it was throughing error.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic is there any Jpql eclipse tool where I can directly run JPQL query.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) _"4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make the Flat table the owner side of the relationship (which make more logical sense IMO). Then you can use a LEFT JOIN instead of a RIGHT JOIN.

```
SELECT uc, MAX(ua.accessTs) FROM Flat Table uc LEFT JOIN uc.User Table ua
```

[Here's why left join on UserTable works:](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

for more detail visit here : [RIGHT JOIN in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210269/right-join-in-jpql)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*`R`*`RIGHT JOIN`*`S`* aka *`R`*`RIGHT OUTER JOIN`*`S`* is the same as

*`S`*`LEFT JOIN`*`R`* aka *`S`*`LEFT OUTER JOIN`*`R`*.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find any (working) examples of a right join in JPQL. As mentioned in this [EclipseLink forum post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368610/), the JPA specification does not include a right join:

> The JPA spec only defines a Left Outer Join. Feel free to file an
>   EclipseLink enhancement or request its inclusion in the JPA
>   specification.

Maybe you can resort to a [native query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)?